# Is it possible to make a viewport with a min-width?

Tags: iphone, css

```
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

to be able to see all the important stuff, on normal desktop, a windows width is always 1000px or more, but on iphone, i like to make sure the screen is 1000px minimum width

is it possible to do that ?

the site that cause problem is : http://www.benoitjacquesdesigner.com/index.html

look at the text on top, it cut .... or explaint to me the white right band (missing background)

--

sub question, is there a place where i can learn by myselft all the mobile trick and tips... i often go to w3school, but people tell some bad stuff about this site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, with some testing that work : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">`

Answer (score 0):

iOS products(so does most Androids) have min-width as 600px, and making it so, will work.
research on `media queries`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-1000, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

Comment: Just make everything HUGE (like a amazing zoom in)

Comment: You can has two diffrent CSS files, one for phone on for computers, see http://webdesign.about.com/od/wireless/a/aa070307.htm

Comment: two css is two time more complicated.. i dont go that way !